# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Software Engineering's [fourth moderator election](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Robert Harvey] [image: GlenH7]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Yannis and World Engineer who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6680232675246080/0).

Comment: yesss. The community made an excellent choice! Congrats Robert and Glen!

Comment: Congratulations to both! I was always surprised to not see that diamond next to Robert Harvey's name, so I'm glad that things are now as they should be.

Comment: Congrats from my side, too. I hope being a mod will not distract you too much from writing answers on this site.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations to Robert and Glen.

I'd also like to give a fond farewell to yannis and World Engineer. You'll be missed, but hopefully you'll stick around and heckle from the sidelines!

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations, you both deserve it!

I hope this will be as fun for you as it has been for me.